# different score between cross_val_score and train_test_split

Tags: python

I met a problem when I was using python3.6 with scikitlearn 0.18

I used the randomforest to do a regression and the regression was pretty good, but when I was trying to compute the cross-validation, I met a problem that the scores got from cross_val_score and train_test_split were really different. The score of train_test_split is 0.9 but the mean of score of cross_val_score is about 0.3.

Could you tell me the reason?
or anything wrong in my code?

the code is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import itertools

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor  
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor     
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score,cross_val_predict,ShuffleSplit,KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
train= np.loadtxt('.txt')
traindata=train[0:,38:]
traintarget=train[0:,j]

rf=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20)   
rf.fit(traindata,traintarget)

X=traindata
Y=traintarget
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
print (rf.score(X_test, Y_test))
score3 = cross_val_score(rf, X, Y, scoring= 'r2',      cv=ShuffleSplit(n=len(X),test_size=0.3,train_size=0.6))
score4 = cross_val_score(rf, X, Y, scoring= 'neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=ShuffleSplit(n=len(X),test_size=0.3,train_size=0.6))
score5 = cross_val_score(rf, X, Y, scoring= 'neg_mean_squared_error', cv=ShuffleSplit(n=len(X),test_size=0.3,train_size=0.6))
print (score3)
print (score4)
print (score5)
```

Comment: I saw someone had the same problem. But I have already added the random sample in both methods.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using train_test_split, you're splitting the dataset into train and test randomly .

Shufflesplit is not too different. The issue may be because the class distribution is highly uneven. (BTW remember one thing, Leave One Out Cross Validation that you're using always gives bad results in my experience). Instead use a 5-fold cross validation.

You can also use stratified cross validation if the class distribution is uneven. It preserves the percentage of samples in each class. Take a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html for example.